# How are vectors defined in terms of sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, vector-spaces, vector-analysis

I'm reading this Wikipedia article on sequences [Sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence) where it mentions 'Sequences over a field may also be viewed as vectors in a vector space.' under vectors section. I'm not able to grasp this, can somebody explain how vectors can be defined in terms of sequences?

Answer (score 2):

The point is: "How do think of 'vectors'?" or "What is a 'vector'?" Here a vector is just seen as an element of a [vector space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition), not as a $n$-tuple of elements from the ground field. The set \[\sideset{^{\mathbb N}}{} F = \{(a_n) \mid a_n \in F, n \in \mathbb N\} \]of sequences of elements from a field $F$
is a vector space over $F$, if we define the vector space operations

- **Addition** The sum of two sequnecens $(a_n), (b_n) \in \sideset{^{\mathbb N}}{} F$ is defined as the sequence $(a_n + b_n)$
- **Scalar multiplication** The product of $\lambda \in F$ with a sequence $(a_n) \in \sideset{^{\mathbb N}}{} F$ is defined as $(\lambda \cdot a_n)$.

Then all [properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition) of a vector space are fulfilled ($\sideset{^{\mathbb N}}{} F$ with $+$ is an abelian group, and we have associativity of the multiplications, distributivity...). That is, sequences are more or less a vector space in the same way finite tuples are, by elementwise operations.

As the sequences form a vector space, we may call them vectors.

Answer (score 1):

In mathematics vector spaces are defined formally by being able to add in them and scalar multiply with an element of the field (for details see the [corresponding Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition)).

You just need to figure out, what both of them is for sequences, but that is not really a problem.

- **Addition:** Let $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ be sequences. We define the addition as follows: $$(a_n) + (b_n) := (c_n) \text{ with } \forall n\in\Bbb N\colon c_n := a_n + b_n$$
- **Multiplication:** Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence and $\lambda$ an element of the underlying field (i.e. $\Bbb R$). Then the multiplication is defined as:
  $$ \lambda (a_n) := (c_n) \text{ with } \forall n\in\Bbb N\colon c_n := \lambda a_n$$

You just need to check all the properties from the definition (like associativity etc.) to see that this indeed defines a vector space, however of infinite dimension.